# how to downlad EMNIST Letters dataset

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, torchvision

```py
# import libraries
import numpy as np  # Corrected indentation and spelling
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F  # Corrected extra space
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset  # Removed extra dot
import copy
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split  # Corrected indentation
# for importing data
import torchvision
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython import display
display.set_matplotlib_formats('svg')  # Corrected indentation and removed extra spaces
```

```py
# download the dataset
cdata = torchvision.datasets.EMNIST(root='emnist', split='letters', download=True)
```

Error:

> URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>

how can i solve this problem?